# R - Subsetting tis object list with logical vector

Tags: r, boolean, time-series, subset, lapply

I want to subset a list of tis objects in R, but am running into an error whenever I try to subset with a logical vector containing all FALSE entries.

For example, given tis object myTis:

```
library(tis)
myTis <- list(cbind(tis(1:10,    start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12), 
                    tis(101:110, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)),
              cbind(tis(7:12,    start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12), 
                    tis(107:112, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)))
```

If I want to find all rows of all the elements of myTis where the first column is greater than 11, that’s easy to do with:

```
myTis %>% lapply(function(x) x[x[,1] < 11,])
```

But when I try to subset it for some value that excludes all the elements of one of the tis objects, I get the following error: *“Error in if (!perhaps) return(FALSE) :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed”*. For example, that error results from running this line:

```
myTis %>% lapply(function(x) x[x[,1] < 7,])
```

Of note, I don't get the error when I try to do something similar with a single tis object:

```
myTis[myTis[[1]][,1] > 10]
```

I'm also open to completely different ways to do this with tis objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason would be that in one of the `list` elements the logical vector is all `FALSE`.  May be we need to create a `if/else` condition to return the original `tis` object in that case or may be `NA` (In the code, we specified `.x` i.e. original object)

```
library(purrr)
myTis %>% 
    map(~  if(!any(.x[,1]< 7)) .x else .x[.x[,1] < 7,])
```

Comment: Ok, this confirms my suspicion that it is due to an error with the tis package that's only avoidable with an if statement like the one you provide. Thanks.